# below 4 xml response no show

Tags: android

i have a this code which work fine for if xml response is above 4 but not print label No Recent Transection if value below or equal 4  this line is correct format to get string length?xmlResponse.length<=4??

```
xmlResponse = www.xyz.xml

 if(xmlResponse.length<=4)
         {

             lblTMSNoRecentTransaction = (TextView) 
   findViewById(R.id.lblTMSNoRecentTransaction);
             lblTMSNoRecentTransaction.setText("No Recent 
     Transactions" );


         }

         else
         {
        //     for (int x=1;x<=xmlResponse.length;)
                {
                 lblTMSCustomTransactionDate = (TextView) 
   findViewById(R.id.lblTMSCustomTransactionDate);
                 lblTMSCustomTransactionDate.setText("Transaction Date :   
  "     + xmlResponse[5][1] );




                 lblTMSCustomAmount = (TextView) 
   findViewById(R.id.lblTMSCustomAmount);
                 lblTMSCustomAmount.setText("Amount : " +   
   xmlResponse[6][1] );



                 lblTMSCustomTransactionDate2 = (TextView)  
   findViewById(R.id.lblTMSCustomTransactionDate2);
                 lblTMSCustomTransactionDate2.setText("Transaction Date : " + xmlResponse[8][1] );




                 lblTMSCustomAmount2 = (TextView) 
    findViewById(R.id.lblTMSCustomAmount2);
                 lblTMSCustomAmount2.setText("Amount : " + 
    xmlResponse[9][1] );




                 lblTMSCustomTransactionDate3 = (TextView)  
  findViewById(R.id.lblTMSCustomTransactionDate3);
                 lblTMSCustomTransactionDate3.setText("Transaction Date : " + xmlResponse[11][1] );




                 lblTMSCustomAmount3 = (TextView)    
 findViewById(R.id.lblTMSCustomAmount3);
                 lblTMSCustomAmount3.setText("Amount : " + 
 xmlResponse[12][1] );



                }

                     }
```

Comment: What type of assignment is this: xmlResponse = www.xyz.xml ?